# How to find and push the data into correct row?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To add a new task i am having the below code,

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>Create New Task</legend>
<input type="text" ng-model="subtaskname" placeholder="Subtask Name" ><br />
<select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
<button type="button" ng-click="addTask()">Add Task</button>
</fieldset>
```

And to make visible of table with the data,

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Age
      </th>
      <th>
        Title
      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <body>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in activity">
      <td>
        {{ data.subTaskNames }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="data.taskShedule" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <button type="button" ng-click="removeTask($index)">Remove Task</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </body>
</table>
```

**Working example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/BoJzDAL8jXYUw1mb9dYK?p=preview

Here in top i am having an input box and a select box to add the sub task name and taskShedule into the table..

Here while adding new data, it should not get added if the taskShedule value already present, in this case the selected taskShedule needs to be finded out and the sub task name needs to be stored inside the string[].

Eg.., In the given above link, If the user tries to add by giving a sub task name in input box and selecting the value from `selectedItem`, if the value is Schedule 1 or Schedule 3 then the new row should not added in the table on click of add task (because the selected schedule already exists) so in this case the newly created sub task name needs to be stored inside the `subTaskNames` array by checking for the `taskShedule` matching with `selectedItem`..
But if the user types any sub task name but he chooses the selectedItem as `Schedule 2`, then new row can be added.(Because there is no existing data available with the selected Schedule)

Kindly help me to store the sub task names into the existing string[] if new data added with existing schedule. If there is no data available with the selection then new row can be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `id` as the `value` instead of an object. You can use `some` to check if the `id` already appears in the `activities`. If it does, then push to the `subTaskNames`, else add the whole activity.

Here is a working example.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
    $scope.items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'schedule1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'schedule2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'schedule3'
      }
    ];

    $scope.activities = [{
        subTaskNames: ['subtask1'],
        taskShedule: 1
      },
      {
        subTaskNames: ['subtask2'],
        taskShedule: 3
      }
    ];

    $scope.addTask = function() {
      if ($scope.activities.some(a => a.taskShedule === $scope.selectedItem)) {
        $scope.activities = $scope.activities.map(a => a.taskShedule === $scope.selectedItem ? {
          subTaskNames: [...a.subTaskNames, $scope.subtaskname],
          taskShedule: $scope.selectedItem
        } : a);
      } else {
        $scope.activities = [...$scope.activities, {
          subTaskNames: [$scope.subtaskname],
          taskShedule: $scope.selectedItem
        }];
      }
    };

    $scope.removeTask = function(index) {
      $scope.activities.splice(index, 1);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <h1>Task List</h1>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create New Task</legend>
    <input type="text" ng-model="subtaskname" placeholder="Subtask Name"><br />
    <select id="s1" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"></select>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addTask()">Add Task</button>
  </fieldset>

  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <body>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in activities">
        <td>{{data.subTaskNames}}</td>
        <td>
          <select ng-model="data.taskShedule" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
            {{item}}
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="removeTask($index)">Remove Task</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </body>
  </table>

</body>
```